# Apache2 proxy Authorization bearer

Tags: apache-http-server

I have developped a JWT authentication based rest API. I am trying to use apache2 as a proxy to my service but it strip the authorization header.

How to make apache2 mod_proxy transmit my Authorization header with Bearer ... content?

Comment: Do you want mod_proxy to preserve the header sent by clients, or do you want it to add a custom header?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want it to preserve the header.